# e4 KeyBinding and Handler depending on selection

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I defined a KeyBinding in my e4 application model. What I want to achieve is that a different handler is used when I press the defined keys - depending on the current selection.

One idea would be to define a common handler which checks the selection and then delegates to the appropriate handler. But I feel this is not optimal and I hope e4 provides some other way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define multiple Binding Contexts each with its own Binding Table. You can then bind the key strokes to different commands in each context.

Use the `EContextService` to activate a particular binding context:

```
@Inject
EContextService contextService;


contextService.activateContext("context id");
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I will try it. But what about the point at which I have to make the context switch - I could of course 'listen' to the current selection and do the switch accordingly. Is there a better way?

Comment: The context is specific to a part so if the selections are in different parts you only need to activate the context when the part is created.

Comment: There is only one part where the selection is happening. Even if I define my own Binding Context and their corresponding Binding Tables I think I still have to change the context every time on selection change and not only set it when the part is created. How else can I decide which context to activate?

Comment: If it is all in one part your original idea of testing in the handler is the most sensible.